# How do I find what kernel module is behind a network interface?

Tags: networking, kernel, interface

How do I find out what kernel module is used for any given network interface?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On the command line run

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

For every network interface you'll get a section starting with `*-network`. Every section hast a `logical name:` line that contains the interface name and a `configuration:` line that contain the driver and some other information.

Answer (score 20):

You can query sysfs to tell you this information. To tell which driver a network interface is using:

```
ls -l /sys/class/net/<devname>/device/driver
```

... where `<devname>` is something like `eth0`. This `driver` directory will be a symlink to the driver node in sysfs.

To get the name of the module that provides that driver:

```
ls -l /sys/class/net/<devname>/device/driver/module
```

... and this `module` directory will be a symlink to the module node in sysfs.

Comment: How to detect virtual drivers (e.g. `veth`)? It's possible with `ethtool -i IFACE_NAME`, but how to find it from sysfs?

Answer (score 9):

IMHO for scripts the best is to use sysfs info (as Jeremy Kerr shows), but for more info:

```
ethtool -i IFACE_NAME
```

E.g.:

```
$ ethtool -i eth0
driver: 8139cp
version: 1.3
firmware-version: 
bus-info: 0000:00:07.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Answer (score 3):

For USB devices you can use the `lsusb` command e.g.:

```
lsusb -t
```